# PySpark: Casting String as Date And Assigning to Variable --> Subset data frame

Tags: date, variables, casting, pyspark, subset

I tried the following code to subset my data so that it only gives me a date range from 6/1 to yesterday:

```
day_1 = '2018-06-01'

df = df.where((F.col('report_date') >= day_1) & (F.col('report_date') < F.current_date()))
```

I get the following error: AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`2018-06-01`' given input columns

Comment: could you please sample data for your data farme

Answer (score 0):

You can use lit method from sql functions to create artificial column.

```
df = df.where((F.col('report_date') >= F.lit(day_1)) & (F.col('report_date') < F.current_date()))
```